# Euler-Lagrange equation in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, geodesics

In Relativity the Lagrangian of a free particle  is
\begin{align} \mathcal L=\sqrt{g_{ab}\frac{dx^a}{d\tau}\frac{dx^b}{d\tau}}\end{align}
Since $\mathcal L$ is parameterization invariant we can always set $$\mathcal L=1.$$ 
In that case how can the Euler-Lagrange equation

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^\mu}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x^\mu} &=0
\end{align}
make sense? How can  $\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot{x}^\mu}$ and $\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial {x}^\mu}$ not be zero?

Comment: $$
f(x,y) = x^2+y^2=1 \quad \stackrel{???}{\Longrightarrow}\quad
\left.
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} & =2x=0\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} & =2y=0
\end{cases}
\right\}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the parametrization interval, say $[a,b]$, is fixed in the [principle of stationary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action), and assumed common to all virtual paths.

If we choose unit parametrizations $L=1$ for all virtual paths, the parametrization interval $[a,b]$ would obvious depend on the virtual path (since not all paths have the same length). As a result, the principle of stationary action is no longer applicable.

TL;DR: We are not allowed to choose unit parametrizations $L=1$ *before* the variation.

*Afterwards* is another story, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/149204/2451).