# Intuition for free-particle action principle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, constrained-dynamics

Consider a particle constrained to a manifold $\mathbb Q$ embedded within standard Euclidean 3-dimensional space that experiences no forces other than constraint forces keeping it within $\mathbb Q$. The Lagrangian in such a case is simply the kinetic energy $T$, so therefore the action $\mathcal S$ minimized by the subsequent motion is as follows, where we take the integration to be along the path taken by the particle.

$$\mathcal S= \int dt\ T$$

The resulting motion of a particle will both be (1) a path of stationary length and (2) constant in $T$. I'm am having trouble visualizing why both of these two properties follow from the action integral stated above.

Even in the simplest case, where $\mathbb Q$ is the one-dimensional $x$-axis of the Cartesian coordinate system, the motion will of course be described by $x(t) = x_0 + v_0 t$, but the action integral reads

$$\mathcal S = \frac{m}{2} \int dt\ \dot x^2.$$

It is not clear to me that minimizing $\int dt\ \dot x^2$ implies that $x(t)$ is linear. Heck, I can't even seem to evaluate that antiderivative in terms of $x$, $\dot x$, $\ddot x$, etc. (nor can [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28dx%2Fdt%29%5E2%20dt), so I'm not sure it can be evaluated with this level of generality.)

Any suggestions on how to make sense of this both in this special case as well as in general? I feel like there must be something simple here I'm missing given how simplified of a case this is. Yes, I could whip out the Euler-Lagrange equations and easily find $m\ddot x = 0$ in this specific case, but I'm looking for as direct and conceptual of a sense of why this is so as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The simple dependence of the action allows us to explicitily show that $\dot x = v_0$ minimizes it. First I claim that the solution $\dot x = v_0$ (consistent with the initial conditions) minimizes the action
$$
S[\dot x] = \int_1^2 \frac 1 2 m\dot{x}^2 \, dt,
$$
with $1$ and $2$ representing the starting and end times respectively.

Now I vary the path by adding a general function of $t$ - let's call it $\delta x$,
$$
x = x_0 + v_0 t  \to x' = (x_0 + v_0t) + \delta x(t),
$$
with $\delta x$ such that $\delta x(1) = \delta x (2) = 0$ in order to respect the boundary conditions. The action changes as follow
$$
S[v_0] \to S[v_0 + \delta \dot{x}] = \frac 1 2 m \int_1^2 (v_0 + \delta \dot{x})^2 \, dt = S[v_0] + mv_0 \int_1^2 \delta \dot{x} \, dt + \frac 1 2 m \int_1^2 (\delta \dot{x})^2 \, dt.
$$

We can easily show that the integral of $\delta \dot{x}$ vanishes because of the boundary conditions imposed on $\delta x$:
$$
\int_1^2 \delta \dot{x} \, dt = \int_1^2 \frac{d}{dt} \delta x \, dt = \delta x(2) - \delta x(1) = 0.
$$
The new action is thus
$$
S[v_0 + \delta \dot{x}] = S[v_0] + \frac 1 2 m \int_1^2  (\delta \dot{x})^2 \, dt.
$$
Since the integrand is always $\geq 0$, the action only increases when we vary the path. Therefore it is a minimum. You can get to the same conclusion in 3 dimensions by replacing $x$ and $\delta x$ by vectors $\mathbf{r}$ and $\delta\mathbf{r}$. This procedure works just because the action has a really simple depence on $x$ and $\dot{x}$ (I think it also works when there is a potential like $V(x) = kx$), but for more general lagrangians you'll not be able to show in this way that the specific solution minimizes the action.

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [D'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) the constraint forces produce no virtual work, so they can be ignored. Since there are no other forces in the otherwise free case, the Lagrangian $L$ for the constrained particle is just given by the pullback of the kinetic term in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the constrained submanifold $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. The solution trajectories are affinely parametrized geodesics on $\mathbb{Q}$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: I agree with what you have said, but I'm not sure how that answers the question at hand.