# Why is the Lagrangian for space-like geodesics equal to 1?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, noethers-theorem, geodesics

In Schwarzschild spacetime, the Lagrangian can be defined as

$$ L = -\left( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \right) \dot{t}^2 + \left( 1- \frac{2M}{r} \right)^{-1} \dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2 + r^2 \sin^2\theta \dot{\phi}^2 $$

where the dot denotes a derivative $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\lambda}$ for an affine parameter $\lambda$.

From Noether's theorem, one can easily prove that the Lagrangian itself if an integral of motion. One can also prove that $\theta = \text{const} =  \pi/2$ without loss of generality. Hence, the quantity $$Q = -\left( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \right) \dot{t}^2 + \left( 1- \frac{2M}{r} \right)^{-1} \dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\phi}^2$$ is a constant of motion.

In my lecture notes, it is claimed without proof that $Q = 1$ for space-like geodesics. It seems like this is rather obvious from the way it is stated but I can't seem to find any proof of this anywhere in my lecture notes nor from Google (after a little bit of searching). Hence, my question is why is this the case and how can one prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The solutions to the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for OP's non-square root Lagrangian $L$ are affinely parametrized geodesics.
2. [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) yields that $L$ is a constant (of motion) along a geodesic, but it is *not* necessarily $1$. For more information, see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/149204/2451).
3. The constant is $1$ if one picks the parameter $\lambda$ to be arclength $s$.