# Does modifying the geodesic Lagrangian $L$ with a smooth function $f(L)$ give the same geodesic curves as solutions?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, variational-principle, geodesics

### Mathematical side of the problem

Given the metric
$$ds^2 = dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta d\varphi^2$$
we can easily construct the action of a free particle
$$S=\alpha \int d\tau \underbrace{\sqrt{\dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2+r^2\sin^2\theta \dot{\varphi}^2}}_{:=L},\quad \text{where}\quad \dot{\vphantom{r}}:=\frac{d}{d\tau}.$$
Consider now the following action
$$\bar{S} := \alpha \int f(L)d\tau, $$
where $f$ is an arbitrary smooth function.

For the specific case $f(g)=g^2/2$ one can show that the resulting equations of motion will describe the same curve, see [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1736730/429233) and [this Phys.SE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/2451).

My question is now if one can generalize this to an arbitrary smooth function $f$? For example, $f(g)=g^2$ seems to work just as well.

### Physic's problem

Even if the above works out form the mathematical side, I'm still confused on why we are allowed to do this in a physics context. The Lagragian is a well defined property for a given physical system, as well as the action. Why can I just square the Lagragian and still get something physically meaningful? What about the parametrization of time? If I change the parametrization, form lets say the eigentime to some arbitrary frame, what happens then to the equations of motion when such a function $f$ is involved?

Comment: Note that if you ensure all derivatives involve the proper time, then $L$ is identically $1$ for a massive particle. Any choice of $f(L)$ will hence give an action that returns the same quantity for any given path (up to a multiplicative constant) --- the proper time along it. The action at the top of your post has the advantage of being invariant under arbitrary reparametrisations $\tau = \tau(\lambda)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Technically it is easier to start from the non-square root Lagrangian
   $$ L_0(x,\dot{x})~:=~ g_{ij}(x) \dot{x}^i \dot{x}^j~\geq~0,\qquad \dot{x}^i~:=~\frac{dx^i}{d\lambda},\tag{1}$$
   and consider the new Lagrangian
   $$ L~:=~f(L_0). \tag{1'}$$
   (This is equivalent to OP's set-up, although the notation is a bit different.)
2. The corresponding energy functions become
   $$h_0~:=~\dot{x}^i\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial \dot{x}^i}-L_0~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~L_0, \tag{2}$$
   and
   $$h~:=~\dot{x}^i\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^i}-L
   ~\stackrel{(1')+(2)}{=}~2L_0f^{\prime}(L_0)-f(L_0)~=:~g(L_0), \tag{2'}$$
   respectively.  The energy functions $L_0$ and $g(L_0)$ are on-shell constants of motion (COM) because of no explicit time dependence, cf. [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem).
3. The EL$^1$ equations for $L_0$:
   $$ \frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial \dot{x}^i}~\approx~\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial x^i}\tag{3}$$ 
   always implies the EL equations for $L$:
   $$ \frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^i}~\approx~\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^i}.\tag{3'}$$

   *Sketched proof of $(3)\Rightarrow (3')$:*
   $$ \begin{align}\frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}^i}~\stackrel{(1')}{=}~&\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(f^{\prime}(L_0)\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial \dot{x}^i}\right) \cr~\stackrel{L_0\text{ COM}}{\approx}&f^{\prime}(L_0)\frac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial \dot{x}^i} ~\stackrel{(3)}{\approx}~f^{\prime}(L_0)\frac{\partial L_0}{\partial x^i}~\stackrel{(1')}{=}~\frac{\partial L}{\partial x^i}.\end{align}\tag{3''}$$ 
   Here we have used the fact that $L_0$ is a COM. $\Box$
4. If $f^{\prime}(L_0)\neq 0$ and $g^{\prime}(L_0)\neq 0$, we can also deduce the other way $(3')\Rightarrow (3)$.

   *Sketched proof of $(3')\Rightarrow (3)$:* Use the fact that $g(L_0)$ is a COM. An application of the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) to eq. (2') then implies that $L_0$ is a COM. Now use eq. (3'') in the opposite direction. $\Box$
5. *Example: The square root Lagrangian.* If $f=\sqrt{\cdot}$, then $g\equiv 0$, so we cannot deduce the other way. The solutions to (3) are affinely parameterized geodesics, while the solutions to (3') are arbitrarily parameterized geodesics, cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/149204/2451).

--

$^1$ *Terminology and Notation:* Equations of motion (EOM) means [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation). The words *on-shell* and *off-shell* refer to whether EOM are satisfied or not. The $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo EOM.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have a couple of questions: 1) When you talk about "on-shell", do you mean that the respective elements satisfy the EoM? 2) What do you mean by "equality modulo EOMs"? I don't really see how I'm supposed to think about this equivalence. 3) Why is there a need to introduce this $\approx$? The third question probably relates to the second, but whenever you write $\approx$ I would have just written $=$..

Comment: I updated the answer. It is often useful to distinguish on-shell and off-shell relations.