# Geodesics: Energy functional vs length functional

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, computational-physics, variational-principle, geodesics, software

The Wikipedia article about [geodesics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Riemannian_geometry) talks about the equivalence of obtaining the geodesic by either minimizing the length functional $L$, or by minimizing the energy functional $L^2/2$, cf. the Phys.SE post [Geodesic Equation from variation: Is the squared lagrangian equivalent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/)

In my courses so far, I haven't heard about the latter technique, so I was curious to see whether both approaches yield the same geodesic. I chose the geodesics on the unit sphere because it has the well-known solution of great circles.

**Minimizing the length functional:**

Given the spherical symmetry of the problem, start with the line element in spherical coordinates:

\begin{equation}
ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin^2\theta\,d\varphi^2
\end{equation}

For $r=1$ and factoring out $d\theta$, we get the arc length as the integral over $ds$:
\begin{equation}
l=\int ds=\int\limits_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\underbrace{\sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta\,\varphi'(\theta)^2}}_{\displaystyle L}\,d\theta
\end{equation}

Then, plug in the Lagrangian $L$ in the Euler-Lagrange equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \varphi}-\frac{d}{d\theta}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \varphi'}=0 \end{equation}

until we arrive at $\displaystyle\varphi(\theta)=\int\frac{C_1}{\sin\theta\sqrt{\sin^2\theta-C_1^2}}\,d\theta$ . This result can be simplified using [eq. (16)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatCircle.html) to yield

\begin{equation}
\varphi(\theta)=-\arcsin\left(\frac{C_1\cot(\theta)}{\sqrt{1-C_1^2}}\right)+C_2
\end{equation}

which, as far as I understand, is the necessary condition for the curve to be a geodesic on the sphere. Insert into the parametrization of the unit sphere:
\begin{equation}
\theta\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} \sin\theta\cos\varphi(\theta) \\ \sin\theta\sin\varphi(\theta) \\ \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Mathematica produces the following plot:

[image: Geodesic (length functional)]

**Minimizing the energy functional:**

Perform the same calculation as above using the squared Lagrangian, multiplied by $1/2$:
\begin{equation}
L^*=\frac{L^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sin^2\theta\,\varphi'(\theta)^2\right)
\end{equation}

The E-L equation yields
\begin{equation}
\varphi(\theta)=\int \frac{C_1}{\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta=-C_1\cot(\theta)+C_2
\end{equation}

This time, the resulting curve does not look like a great circle whenever $C_1\neq 0$. What did I miss?

[image: Geodesic (energy functional)]

---

Mathematica code for the first plot:

```
\[CurlyPhi][\[Theta]_, C1_, C2_] := -ArcSin[(C1 Cot[\[Theta]])/Sqrt[1 - C1^2]] + C2
Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot3D[sphere[{\[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]}], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {White, Opacity[0.6]}, ImageSize -> 500, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[CurlyPhi][\[Theta], C1, C2]], Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[CurlyPhi][\[Theta], C1, C2]], Cos[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, t}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5]], {{C1, 0}, -1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{C2, 0}, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t, \[Pi]/2}, 0, 2 \[Pi], Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong Lagrangian. You have two degrees of freedom $\theta,\phi$ and you need an additional “time” parameter to parametrize your trajectories. I’ll denote it $t$ so you are looking for equations of motion of $\theta(t),\phi(t)$.

These are given by two possible Lagrangians:
$$
L=\frac{1}{2}(\dot\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\dot\phi^2)
$$
Or $L’=\sqrt{2L}$.

In the first case, you have the equations of motion derived by Euler-Lagrange:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\dot\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta\dot\phi^2&=0 \\
\frac{d}{dt}(\sin^2\theta\dot\phi )&= 0
\end{align}
In the second case, the equations of motion are:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{ds}-\sin\theta\cos\theta \frac{d\phi}{ds}^2&=0 \\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sin^2\theta \frac{d\phi}{ds}\right) &= 0
\end{align}
with:
$$
\frac{d}{ds}=\frac{1}{L’}\frac{d}{dt}
$$

In either case, the curves will trace out great circles.

It is only in the second case that you have  the curves are invariant by reparametrization (a case of gauge invariance). This is why you could remive a degree of freedom and parametrize the curve by $\theta$. However this is not true in the second case. The parametrization is fixed (it’s the arclength) and reparametrizing does not give you the same curves as you’ve observed.

In fact this is how you can go from $L’$ to $L$. You can lift gauge invariance by choosing the arclength as the parameter, adding an additional constraint.

Hope this helps.

**Answer to comment**

The usual method for solving such systems is by noticing that you have enough conservation laws for the system to be integrable. You have naturally two conserved quantities from direct inspection:
$$
E=\frac{1}{2}(\dot\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\dot\phi^2) \\
L_z=\sin^2\theta\dot\phi
$$
Actually, your system is superintegrable since you also have the other components of angular momentum that are also conserved.

You can use them to get a first order ODE in $\theta$ only:
$$
\dot\theta=\sqrt{2E-\frac{L_z^2}{\sin^2\theta}}
$$
You need only calculate the antiderivative of the inverse of the RHS. This can be done analytically using the change of variables to $z=\cos\theta$ and using the $\arccos$.

If you only wanted an equation of $\phi(\theta)$ as before, you could also manipulate the equations to get:
$$
\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}=\frac{L_z}{\sin\theta\sqrt{2E\sin^2\theta-L_z^2}}
$$
which can be integrated in a similar fashion.

Comment: In other words: the Lagrangian in my length functional is correct and I can get away with the $\varphi(\theta)$ dependency, for the energy functional I have no choice but to use the more general $\theta(t), \varphi(t)$ parametrization. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes that’s what I meant

Comment: So, for the squared Lagrangian we get the ODE system $\frac{d}{dt}\dot{\theta}-\sin\theta\cos\theta\,\dot{\phi}^2=0, \frac{d}{dt}\left(\sin^2\theta\,\dot{\phi}\right)=0$.
How would I go about soving it analytically? My goal was to use the energy functional to get rid of the square root, and to have some closed form solution as for the non-squared Lagrangian.

Comment: Re your edit: I tried to solve $\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}=\,...\,$ to get $\phi(\theta)$ but if I plug in the expressions for $E$ and $L_z$, $\dot{\phi}$ and $\dot{\phi}^2$ pop up again. Or can I treat $E$ and $L_z$ as constant?

Comment: Yes the point of the method is to identify constants of motion in order to revert to the case of independent first order ODE’s. $E,L_z$ are to be treated as constants, determined by the initial conditions.

Comment: OK, that brings up the question how to determine $E$ and $L_z$: Given two points on the sphere $p_1=(\theta_1,\phi_1)$, $p_2=(\theta_2,\phi_2)$ how do I come up with the ICs?
In my example for the length functional, I would have inserted $p_1,p_2$ in the equation for $\varphi(\theta)$ to get the integration constants $C_1$ and $C_2$. How do I do that for $E$ and $L_z$?

Comment: Just solve the ODE and you get a system of equations by evaluating at the two points. This is just like your method, only instead of having $C_1,C_2$ you have $E,L_z$.

Comment: Small caveat: the variational problem is nice and regular as long as the second point is sufficiently close to the first one. Caustics can appear when the second point is too far. In the case of the sphere, this corresponds to the case when the two points are antipodal. In physics, the Cauchy problem is often more relevant. This gets rid of the caustic problems, and simplifies the determination of constants of motion. They can be deduced from the initial conditions.

Comment: After integrating $\frac{d\phi}{d\theta}$ I end up with $\phi(\theta)=-\arctan{\frac{L_z\cos\theta}{\sqrt{E(1-\cos(2\theta))-L_z^2}}}+C$, but now I have one additional constant to take care of - do I need another constraint, or can I simply drop it?

Comment: Just match your boundary conditions. You have two equations for three variables, so your system is over determined. This is to be expected since for the Cauchy problem, you have three parameters (initial position initial direction).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "match your boundary conditions" - maybe a worked example will clear this up for me: Let $p_1=(\pi/4,0)$, $p_2=(\pi/2,\pi/4)$.
Then, in order to determine $E$ and $L_z$, insert $p_1,p_2$ in $\phi(\theta)=-\arctan...$, which still leaves $C$ undetermined. Maybe it is easy but I don't see it.

Comment: I didn’t do the math, but unless $p_1,p_2$ are antipodal, the system of two equations is degenerate in some sense.  Its solutions (triplet of constants) should form a discrete set

Comment: In my example above, $p_1,p_2$ are not antipodal - $p_1$ is 45° above the equator, while $p_2$ lies on the equator and 45° rotated counter-clockwise wrt $p_1$. I did not expect the squared Lagrangian to be that troublesome to solve, so went back to see if my first method using the "classic" Lagrangian yields the correct geodesic: I get $C_1=1/\sqrt{3}$, $C_2=\pi/4$ which yields a great circle through $p_1,p_2$, as expected.

Comment: To sum it up: we have three variables $E$, $L_z$ and $C$ but only two equations which cannot be solved unless one variable is eliminated or there is one additional equation.

Comment: As I said, the equation is degenerate. The idea is that $(E,L_z,C)$ and $(\lambda^2 E,\lambda L_z,C)$ give the same trajectory for any $\lambda$. This amounts to rescaling the the time parameter, which does not affect the trajectory. Without loss of generality, you can assume $E=1$ for example (essentially parametrising by the arc length), so you have two unknowns for two equations, which uniquely determine $L_z,C$ (with the usual caveat for antipodal points)

Comment: Indeed, now I get great circles from using the solution to the squared Lagrangian as well. How do we know there is a square relationship between $\lambda^2E$ and $\lambda L_z$? Or maybe more importantly, can you recommend some books which discuss these details?

Comment: As I mentioned before, it's dimensional analysis on the units of time. $E$ has dimension $T^{-2}$ while $L_z$ has dimension $T^{-1}$. I don't have any references in mind, but your questions are more about differential geometry rather than about physics.